Is police confiscation of legal Delta 9 products in PA justified in this instance?
As a resident of PA, it is my understanding that Delta 9 products derived from hemp with a sufficiently low concentration are legal in the state of PA for use and retail sale. This is why I was shocked to find out that several vape shops in my local area fell victim to what I imagine is police and district attorney overreach in the form of inventory confiscation of all Delta 9 THC containing products from pretty much all vape shops in the jurisdiction. Events are reference here: https://triblive.com/local/valley-news-dispatch/police-raid-2-vape-shops-in-lower-burrell/
I personally know the family of the DA and it wouldn't surprise me if she was caught over-reaching here. The claim here is roughly that there is "evidence" that one or more shops have been failing to ID customers on these items and that some of these products wound up in the hands of a minor. I interviewed two of the shop owners in my area for comment and both claimed to me that they are not under any criminal investigation that they are aware of and vociferously claimed that they would never have sold anything that was even legally dubious and that this broad overreach is going to considerably hurt them as these legal products were some of their best selling items.
What justification exists in cases like this where police can confiscate a businesses inventory of legal items even though they are not suspect of any criminal behavior?

Your claim that the classification of all product by a certain manufacturer as violating a statute is overreach is unsubstantiated and needs to be clarified.

The article you link seems pretty clear about why the raids happened. First was selling to students when by state law you need to either be 21 or if you are active duty or a vet be 18. Second it appears that undercover bought products that exceeded the levels allowed by the law. "Over those months, detectives bought products that contained the illegal cannabis-derived substance Delta 8 and higher concentration levels of Delta 9 than are allowed under state law."

@JoeW sounds like an answer.

@ohwilleke Wasn't sure if that would be a good answer or not but I have provided an answer now.

"vociferously claimed that they would never have sold anything that was even legally dubious" Of course they would claim that.

@Questor But don't you think it odd that literally every single vape shop in the county were all in violation here?  I know what the article from this extremely law-enforcement biased rag had stated, and if I am wrong then I will be humble enough to admit as much, however I am skeptical. This DA has had a history of egregious civil rights violations in the past under the supposed guise of "WON'T SOMEONE THINK OF THE CHILDREN?!"

@maple_shaft Not really. As vapes are targeted at kids. Nicotine use among teenagers had dropped to an all time low, as very few kids were using cigarettes, thanks to years of work to make cigarettes look uncool to teenagers. And than vapes were introduced and the number of kids using nicotine products skyrockets (Vapes).

The article you linked seems pretty clear on why this happened.

“This investigation has been ongoing for several months,” she said.
“Detectives received information that students from several local
school districts were caught with THC vapes and vape cartridges and
allegedly purchased those cartridges from stores in and around the
Westmoreland County area.”
Over those months, detectives bought products that contained the
illegal cannabis-derived substance Delta 8 and higher concentration
levels of Delta 9 than are allowed under state law.
In Pennsylvania, it’s illegal to sell or consume Delta 8 products,
Ziccarelli said. Delta 9 products with a concentration of more than 3%
THC are illegal. THC is the psychoactive ingredient of marijuana.
Customers must be 21 or older to purchase legal Delta 9 products.

Not only are they being investigated for illegal sales to underage customers but they are being investigated for selling products above the legal concentration levels.
Disregarding the THC part of the issue it is also illegal to sell vape products to people under the age of 21 (or 18 if they are active military or a vet)
What Parents and Students Need to Know About Vaping in and out of school in Pennsylvania & New Jersey

Pennsylvania strictly prohibits the sale of electronic cigarettes or
vapors or vapes to persons under the age of 21 or under the age of 18
if the person is in the military or a veteran.  Self service displays
of vapes are restricted to tobacco stores.

Overall it seems that the reasons for the actions fall clearly within the law.

Isn't it odd though that somehow every single vape shop in the county were all targeted in these raids?  What are the chances that every single one were actually selling illegal items?

@maple_shaft the article you linked clearly says why the raid happened and there is a large problem across the country with underage students buying and using vape products.

@JoeW If it weren't grossly illegal one might think that vapes target audience was children. what with the packaging, design and childish flavors that vapes. Oh wait: https://time.com/6271149/juul-settlement-marketing-kids/ guess I am not the only one to think this. Apparently a judge thought that a vape company placing adds on a children's tv network was a step too far. Too bad they only delivered a slap in the wrist.
